# Spring Boot Query by Example not working with passed in argument

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am having a problem that when i set my parameter for my class from the Entity does not search on the parameter that i am passing n

In my Controller Class

```
     ExampleMatcher registrationMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAny()
            .withMatcher("registration", startsWith())
            .withIgnoreCase()  

 @GetMapping("/nnumber/{registration}")
    public List<Airplane> searchByRegistration(String registration) {
        Airplane airplane = new Airplane();
        airplane.setRegistration(registration);
        Example<Airplane> example = Example.of(airplane, registrationMatcher);
        return airplaneRepository.findAll(example);
    }
```

In my log I see this for Hibernate.

```
select a1_0.id,a1_0.cruise_speed,a1_0.gph,a1_0.make,a1_0.model,a1_0.registration,a1_0.useful_load,a1_0.year from airplane a1_0
```

Its not using the `airplane.setRegistration(registration);`

However if I set the registration like this. `airplane.setRegistration("6254NG");`

then it will find anything that matches that contains "6254NG"

```
select a1_0.id,a1_0.cruise_speed,a1_0.gph,a1_0.make,a1_0.model,a1_0.registration,a1_0.useful_load,a1_0.year from airplane a1_0 where lower(a1_0.registration) like ? escape '\\'
```

I am trying to search on what the registration is set to from the GetMapping. I.E if 6 is passed it it will find anything starting with 6

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is that you forgot to add the `@PathVariable` in the method 'searchByRegistration',it should look like this `public List<Airplane> searchByRegistration(@PathVariable String registration)`.